# Formatting numbers consistently in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, string-formatting

I have a series of numbers:

```
from numpy import r_
r_[10**(-9), 10**(-3), 3*10**(-3), 6*10**(-3), 9*10**(-3), 1.5*10**(-2)]
```

and I would like to have them displayed in a plot's legend in the form:

```
a 10^(b)
```

(with `^` meaning superscript)

so that e.g. the third number becomes `3 10^(-3)`.

I know I have to use Python's string formatting operator `%` for this, but I don't see a way to do this. Can someone please show me how (or show me an alternative way)?

Comment: you can also try str.format - http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: How are you creating the plot? Is it just some ASCII-art-like plot or you are using `matplotlib` or other libraries?

Comment: does `'%s 10^(%s)' % (number1, number2)` work?

Comment: @Bakuriu I'm using `matplotlib`. I'll add the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are sure you don't need more than a fixed number of places after the decimal dot, then:

```
>>> from numpy import r_
>>> a = r_[10**(-9), 10**(-3), 3*10**(-3), 6*10**(-3), 9*10**(-3), 1.5*10**(-2)]
>>> for x in a: print "%.1e"%x
... 
1.0e-09
1.0e-03
3.0e-03
6.0e-03
9.0e-03
1.5e-02
```

The catch here is that were you to use `%.0e` as a format, the last number would be printed as `1e-2`

**EDIT**: Since you're using `matplotlib`, then it's a different story:  you could use the TeX rendering engine. A quick-and-dirty example:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = 1.5*10**(-2)
l = ("%.0e"%x).split("e")
x_str = r"$ %s \times 10^{%s}$" % (l[0], l[1] )

ax.set_title(x_str)

plt.show()
```

which would indeed be a little cleaner with new `.format` string formatting.

**EDIT2**: Just for completeness and future reference, here's my take on the OP's way from the comments:

```
x = 1.5*10**(-2)
l = ("%.0e"%x).split("e")
x_str = r"$%s \times 10^{%s}$" % ( l[0], str(int(l[1])) )
```

Here I'm converting to an int and back to avoid leading zeros: `-02` -> `-2` etc.

Comment: I believe this is not what he wanted. I see no superscript here.

Comment: Is there a way to 1) put the exponent in superscript, and 2) replace the `e` with a `10`?

Comment: @Zhenya OK, I'm almost there. Problem is that `frexp` returns base-2 decompositions, which is not quite what I want. I can't seem to find frexp10 or equivalent. The format string way is: `'{0}.10^{1}'.format(round(f,1),e)` which only leaves the superscript to be typeset by TeX.

Comment: @rubenv: yes, indeed, what I said was wrong, it's a base-2 exponent. OK, just split the string on `e`, then collect it all together -- have edited it into the answer.

Comment: @rubenvb: what I have now is still dirty, as it's leaving extra zeros in the base-10 exponent (e^{-01} etc).

Comment: And it's not cooperating with TeX's braces in conjunction with `.format`. Not that big of a problem though... This is what I have now: `l = ("%1.1e"%kapparange[i]).split("e-0"); plot3.plot(theta2, m0amplitude[i,:], label = '$\\kappa=%s \\times 10^{%s}$'%(l[0],'-'+l[1]))`, which is hacky, but works :)

Comment: @rubenvb: Two comments on your final way: 1. I'd avoid splitting on "e-0" --- this'll break once you have "e-12" or "e+1". Better keep splitting on just "e", then convert to an int and back to string. 2. I'd avoid manually escaping TeX controls: raw strings fit the bill much more cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

```
list_item = (multiply_number,degree_number)
displayed_items = [list_item, list_item, ....]
for item in displayed_items:
   print '{0}*10^({1})'.format(*item)
```

Create list of tupels with number you want to display. And just output them using format(). Don't forget to use *(this for using each item in tuple).